# How to get the updated scroll position while scrolling RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view and I am scrolling it by smoothScrollToPosition function. I want a listener which will trigger every time recycler view scrolls and give me the value of the position while scrolling.
For Example, if I set to recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(15) so I want the listener to be triggered on every position it scrolled, in this case, it should be triggered and give result 0,1,2,3,4 up to 15.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the current position do this in onScrollListener()

```
private var currentVisibleItemRecyclerView = -1
    private var linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager? = null
```

then in `onCreate()` declare layout manager, set it to `recyclerview` and set `onScrollListener`

```
linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager)
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(recyclerViewOnScrollListener)
```

where recyclerViewOnScrollListener

```
   private val recyclerViewOnScrollListener: RecyclerView.OnScrollListener =
        object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
            
            }

            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
                val visibleItemCount: Int = linearLayoutManager!!.getChildCount()
                val totalItemCount: Int = linearLayoutManager!!.getItemCount()
                val firstVisibleItemPosition: Int =
                    linearLayoutManager!!.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
                currentVisibleItemRecyclerView = firstVisibleItemPosition + visibleItemCount
                Log.d(
                    " Position",
                    " currentVisibleItemRecyclerView  " + currentVisibleItemRecyclerView.toString()
                )

            }
        }
```

Comment: what is the use of totalitemcount

Comment: do not use it if there is no need